# Why did my DAX SUMX return this result? Results are doubled

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dax function created like this:

```
total_calls = SUMX(Agent_Performance_Summary,[acd_call_count] + [non_acd_call_count])
```

My results look like this:

```
call_date     agent_id     agent_name     acd_call_count     non_acd_call_coiunt     total_calls
2021-01-01    1            john_doe       0                  9                       18
```

Why is this? Why is my `total_calls` not 9?

Comment: What does your data table look like?

Comment: It's about 1000 + rows with the same data (minus the total column). Did you want me to paste the table DDL?

Comment: Nah, just a few representative rows. Let's say all rows that match the first three columns in your posted results. Also, please clarify if [acd_call_count] and [non_acd_call_count] are columns or measures.